# Count of view week by week

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking to plot the number of views on an investment every week from creation date to current date.
[image]

Every time someone visits an investment, I'm inserting it to a table with
`investment_id`, `user_id` and `timestamp(datetime)`.

Table looks like this:

investment_id

```
investment_id  user_id     Time_stamp
499            233         2015-01-22 09:00:42
499            256         2015-01-21 09:00:42
499            275         2015-01-20 09:00:42
499            233         2015-01-14 09:00:42
499            233         2015-01-14 09:00:42
499            233         2015-01-10 09:00:42
499            273         2015-01-06 09:00:42
499            347         2015-01-02 09:00:42
499            343         2015-01-01 09:00:42
499            344         2015-01-01 09:00:42
```

So for investment_id 499 created on 2015-01-01 00:00:00, the result will be as below:

```
Week       Views
1          4
2          3
3          2
4          1
```

Found a work around:

```
SELECT  (CASE (ceiling(datediff(Time_stamp,"2015-01-01 00:00:00")/7)) WHEN 0 THEN 1 
ELSE (ceiling(datediff(Time_stamp,"2015-01-01 00:00:00")/7)) END) as weeks, 
count(Investment_Id) as viewCount 
from log_table where Investment_Id =499 group by weeks
```

Comment: show your query what you tried

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY. Investment 499 was viewed twice at the same time by user 233. This is problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed is a temporary/virtual table like this:

```
+ ------------- + ---------- + ---------- + ---------- +
| investment_id | week_start | week_end   | weeknumber |
+ ------------- + ---------- + ---------- + ---------- +
| 499           | 2015-01-02 | 2015-01-09 | 1          |
| 499           | 2015-01-09 | 2015-01-16 | 2          |
| 499           | 2015-01-16 | 2015-01-23 | 3          |
| 499           | 2015-01-23 | 2015-01-30 | 4          |
+ ------------- + ---------- + ---------- + ---------- +
```

This can be accomplished with a kind of generate series:

```
SELECT
    499 investment_id,
    @wstart := @startdate + INTERVAL @wseq * 7 DAY week_start,
    @wend := @wstart + INTERVAL 7 DAY week_end,
    @wseq := @wseq + 1 weeknumber
FROM
    information_schema.collations
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT @startdate := (SELECT MIN(DATE(time_stamp)) 
     FROM log_table
     WHERE investment_id = 499), @wseq := 0) u
HAVING
    week_start <= CURRENT_DATE
```

The cross join is to initiate the user variables, with a table with enough rows you can generate series from that user variables. information_schema.collations is always available and has over 200 rows.

If you put this in a subquery the table with investment views can be joined on the investent_id and the time_stamp between week_start and week_end.

This will result in:

```
SELECT
    s.weeknumber,
    COUNT(v.user_id) views
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        499 investment_id,
        @wstart := @startdate + INTERVAL @wseq * 7 DAY week_start,
        @wend := @wstart + INTERVAL 7 DAY week_end,
        @wseq := @wseq + 1 weeknumber
    FROM
        information_schema.collations
    CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT @startdate := (SELECT MIN(DATE(start_date))
         FROM log_table
         WHERE investment_id = 499), @wseq := 0) u
    HAVING
        weekstart <= CURRENT_DATE
    ) s
LEFT JOIN
    log_table v
    ON s.investment_id = v.investment_id
    AND v.time_stamp >= s.week_start
    AND v.time_stamp < s.week_end
GROUP BY s.weeknumber
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
select week(time_stamp), count(investment_id)
group by time_stamp, investment_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Two Options:

1. Use DatePart method to get the week from the datetime column, 
   However this will not give you the expected result, since the 6th does not fall in the same calendar week as the 1st and the 2nd of January, as your output suggests.
2. Use a "custom" code that determines what is a week, I.e. the first week is between the 1st and the 7th of each month, etc.

Examples for the two options are below,

good luck.

```
    SELECT  *
    into #tmp
    FROM    
    (
    select  499 investment_id,            233 user_id,         '2015-01-22 09:00:42' Time_stamp
        union all
    select  499,            256,         '2015-01-21 09:00:42'
        union all
    select  499,            275,         '2015-01-20 09:00:42'
        union all
    select  499,            233,         '2015-01-14 09:00:42'
        union all
    select  499,            233,         '2015-01-14 09:00:42'
        union all
    select  499,            233,         '2015-01-10 09:00:42'
        union all
    select  499,            273,         '2015-01-06 09:00:42'
        union all
    select  499,            347,         '2015-01-02 09:00:42'
        union all
    select  499,            343,         '2015-01-01 09:00:42'
        union all
    select  499,            344,         '2015-01-01 09:00:42'
    ) a


    Select DATEPART(wk,Time_stamp) week , count(investment_id)
    FROM    #tmp
    group by DATEPART(wk,Time_stamp)


SELECT  b.WeekNumber , count(b.investment_id)
FROM    (
    SELECT  a.* , 
        case 
            when a.DayInMonth between 1 and 7 then 1
            when a.DayInMonth between 8 and 14 then 2
            when a.DayInMonth between 16 and 22 then 3
            when a.DayInMonth between 23 and 29 then 4
            else 5
        end as WeekNumber               
    FROM    (
        Select day(Time_stamp) DayInMonth , *
        FROM    #tmp
    ) a
)b
group by b.WeekNumber
```

Comment: Is the second statement what you are looking for?

Comment: I wasnt clear about week i think. If the creation date is Jan 10, then by first week i meant Jan 10-17, second week means Jan 18-24 and so on

Comment: That's a customization you'll have to do, since you know the date from which you start counting, but I provided with the basic template for you to achieve it.